# JQuery Deferred, Promises with SharePoint List

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, deferred

I'm running the following code to get SharePoint list items using JQuery Deferred/Promises to do something with that list. But when I run the code I get the error:

> 'The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.'

Please find the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Do not execute jsom until sp.js file has loaded.
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(createGamesCloudDashboard, "sp.js");});
    //Function to retrieve Games Cloud Order Book from SharePoint server.
    function createGamesCloudDashboard() {
       getGamesCloudOrderBook().then(
         outputGamesCloudRevenue(gamesCloudItems),     
         function (sender, args) { 
           console.log('An error occurred while retrieving Games Cloud Order Books.')
         });
    }

   //CAML Query definition.
   function getGamesCloudOrderBook() {
       // Create Deferred object to run the consumer of 
       // the Games Cloud Order Book synchronously.
       var deferred = $.Deferred();
       var clContext = new SP.ClientContext('some url');
       var spList = clContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Name of List');   
       var gamesCloudOrderBook = new SP.CamlQuery();
       this.gamesCloudItems = spList.getItems(gamesCloudOrderBook);
       clContext.load(gamesCloudItems);
       clContext.executeQueryAsync(
         Function.createDelegate(this, 
           function () { deferred.resolve(gamesCloudItems) }),
         Function.createDelegate(this, 
           function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args) }));

       return deferred.promise();
   }

   function outputGamesCloudRevenue(gamesCloudItems) {
       //do something with the list.
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.then()` expects named or anonymous function delegates as parameters.

In the following piece of code...

```
getGamesCloudOrderBook().then(
     outputGamesCloudRevenue(gamesCloudItems),     
     function (sender, args) { 
       ...        
    });
```

...you're not passing in the function `outputGamesCloudRevenue` as the first parameter, you're actually executing the function (with the undefined variable `gamesCloudItems` as its parameter) and then passing the executed function's return value (if any) to `.then()`.

Try this instead:

```
 getGamesCloudOrderBook().then(
     outputGamesCloudRevenue,     
     function (sender, args) { 
       console.log('An error occurred while retrieving Games Cloud Order Books.')
     });
```

Comment: Hi Thriggle, Thanks very much for the answer! That works. I got it to work with callbacks, but I really wanted to understand and use jQuery deferred/promises.